# Unreadable $ characters in .NET assembly ported from Jar

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly, ikvm

I have a DLL assembly that I ported from a JAR (using IKVM). While it appears to be a valid assembly, it contains types whose names have a '$' character. I am able to see these types in the Object Explorer in Visual Studio and through Reflection, but I cannot type the names in code without intellisense/build errors saying the '$' is unexpected.

Here is some of the decompiled code:

```
  public sealed class PFAEngine$ : Object
  {
    internal static PFAEngine$ __<>MODULE$;

    public static PFAEngine$ MODULE$
    {
      get
      {
        return PFAEngine$.__<>MODULE$;
      }
    }

    static PFAEngine$()
    {
      PFAEngine$ pfaEngine = new PFAEngine$();
    }
  }
```

Is this simply a limitation of the Visual Studio / MSBuild? Is there any way to reference these types without resorting to Reflection?

Comment: I think you're gonna have to use reflection.  Those look like obfuscated symbols.

Comment: They are auto-generated classes that implement language features like iterators and lambda expressions.  Using characters like `$` and `<>` is intentional to ensure the auto-generated name can never accidentally match a name used by the programmer.  Nothing particularly jumps out from this one, but I know that the vb.net compiler likes to use $.  But surely it is IKVM doing this.  Decompiling the DLL is not intended to be useful.